# return time since last occurrence of a string for certain days of the week only

Tags: excel

I am working on a scheduling sheet. I want to calculate the distance in weeks since a person was last scheduled on one of 3 different 'jobs'. I only want to look at the time since someone was last scheduled on a weekend, and individuals may be scheduled on weekdays intervening between the last weekends.

For example:

```
Date    Day_of_week Task_a  Task_b  Task_c  Distance_a  Distance_b  Distance_c
7/1/2015    Wednesday   Ed      Mary    Amy     0   0   0
7/2/2015    Thursday    Bill    Judy    Bob     0   0   0
7/3/2015    Friday      Ed      Mary    Amy     0   0   0
7/4/2015    Saturday    Ed      Mary    Amy     0   0   0
7/5/2015    Sunday      Ed      Mary    Amy     0   0   0
7/6/2015    Monday      Bill    Mary    Bob     0   0   0
7/7/2015    Tuesday     Ed      Judy    Amy     0   0   0
7/8/2015    Wednesday   Ed      Amy     Bob     0   0   0
7/9/2015    Thursday    Bob     Ed      Judy    0   0   0
7/10/2015   Friday      Ed      Bob     Judy    0   0   0
7/11/2015   Saturday    Ed      Bob     Judy    7   0   0
7/12/2015   Sunday      Ed      Bob     Amy     7   0   7
```

gives the correct distances for each of the 3 tasks with labels for cells first followed by new line of data at each date.

For Distance A I have attempted:

```
{=IF(AND(B3="Saturday", (A3-MAX(IF($C$2:E2=C3, $A$2:A2, 0)))/7 <53),  (A3-MAX(IF($C$2:E2=C3, $A$2:A2, 0)))/7, ".")}
```

which returns a value on each Saturday (as intended), but cannot scan past the most recent weekday assignment, giving falsely low values. I have attempted other `IF(OR) & IF(AND)` statements but the first failure generates a false value effectively ceasing the program.

Any assistance with code and formatting the example to .csv or tab seperated values would be appreciated.

Comment: Can I just clarify, would you like the answers in whole weeks because it looks as if the answers for Ed and Amy should be 6 or 7 days i.e. roughly one whole week?

Comment: Thanks- whole weeks would be best, though getting the correct date in the right half of the equation is the challenge I'm having.

Answer (score 0):

OK so just to recap you need to calculate the distance in weeks from the current date to date of the previous job scheduled at the weekend. 
The conditions are:-

```
Current date must fall on a weekend
Previous date must also be on a weekend
Previous date must not be on same weekend as current date
Must be same person.
```

I've found it easier to use the WEEKDAY function to check if the dates fall on a weekend, so putting this all together I get:-

```
=IF(WEEKDAY($A3,16)>=3,"",
    IF(MAX($A$2:$A2*(C$2:C2=C3)*(WEEKDAY($A$2:$A2,16)<3)*(($A3-$A$2:$A2)>1))=0,"",
      INT(($A3-MAX($A$2:$A2*(C$2:C2=C3)*(WEEKDAY($A$2:$A2,16)<3)*(($A3-$A$2:$A2)>1))+1)/7)
    )
  )
```

to be entered as an array formula in row 3 using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

I think the general logic of your formula is OK, but OR and AND functions don't work very well in array formulas so I have replaced ANDs with multiplications.

At the moment this only checks for a person appearing in the *same* column so I will post another version if it needs to check across the three columns.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I had not used multiplications and appreciate your approach. I will attempt to adapt to all three columns given this starting point.